# Finding a Node in a Tree using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, tree, data, parent=None):

        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []   
        self.tree = tree

     def find(self, x):

        if self.data is x:
            return self
        elif self.children:
            for node in self.children:
                return node.find(person)
        else:
            return None
```

I am really stuck, i can't seem to create a method in my Node class that finds a Node with data x and returns that Node. If no Node is found, it will return None.

Answer (score 2):

you're searching for `parent` in children, while you should search for `x`

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self, tree, data, parent=None):
        self.data = data
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []   
        self.tree = tree

    def find(self, x):
        if self.data is x: return self
        for node in self.children:
            n = node.find(x)
            if n: return n
        return None


>>> n = Node(None, 1)
>>> n.children = [Node(None, 2), Node(None, 3)]
>>> print n.find(3).data
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the immediate fix would be to change this

```
    for node in self.children:
        return node.find(person)
```

To this

```
    for node in self.children:
        res = node.find(person)
        if res is not None:
            return res
```